# How should I connect dictionary's user_id & model's user_id?

Tags: python, django

I wanna parse excel& make dictionary and connect the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary.
Now dictionary is

```
dict_data = {'user_id': 1,'nationarity': America, 'dormitory':'A', 'group': 3}
```

Models in views.py is

```
user = User(user_id=rows[1],name_id=rows[2],age=rows[3],employee=rows[4])
```

If I wanna add dictionary's data to model,I should write like

```
for data in dict_data:
    User(**data)
```

but how should I connect dictionary's user_id& models' one?What should I write it?

Now I wrote like

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from app.models import User
book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/XXX.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
headers = sheet3.row_values(0)

large_item = None
dicts = {}
for row_index in range(sheet3.nrows):
    rows3 = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows3[1] or large_item

    # Create dict with headers and row values
    row_data = {}
    for idx_col, value in enumerate(rows3):
        header_value = headers[idx_col]
        # Avoid to add empty column. A column in your example
        if header_value:
            row_data[headers[idx_col]] = value
            # Add row_data to your data_dict with
    dicts[row_index] = row_data
    for data in dicts:
        user1 = User.objects.filer(user_id = data['user_id']).exists()
        if user1:
            user1.__dict__.update(**dicts)
            user1.save()
```

When I run this code,

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'filer'
user1 = User.objects.filer(user_id = data['user_id']).exists()
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for data in dict_datas:        
    user = User.object.filter(user_id = data['user_id']).exists()
    if user:
       user.__dict__.update(**dict_data)
       user.save()
```

Comment: I wrote ur code, but error happens.I updated my question, if u know something please help me.

Comment: "filer" should be "filter"

Answer (score 1):

`dict_data` you posted is a dict,you shouldn't iterate it like a list.
I guess your `dict_data` is a list of dict, so:

```
for data in dict_datas:
    user = User.objects.get(user_id=data['user_id'])
    user.name_id = data['**']
    ...
    user.save()
```

First, fetch the user object with `user_id` in your xecel&dict, then change the value, and save it.