# How can I add new data to exist model?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel& make dictionary and connect the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary.I parsed excel and got lists(`rows2`) like `['1', 'Bob', 'America', '', '', 0.0]`I wanna added this list data to User model.
`views.py` is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()

book2 = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel2.xlsx')
sheet2 = book2.sheet_by_index(0)
headers = sheet2.row_values(0)

large_item = None
data_dict = {}
for row_index in range(sheet2.nrows):
    rows2 = sheet2.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows2[1] or large_item
```

What should I write after this last code?
models.py is

I made area data model in models.py.

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I wanna put `rows2[2]` in country,`rows2[3]` in a,`rows2[4]` in b,`rows2[5]` in c.

Comment: HI can you convert as dict with key

Comment: @Robert thx ur comments,I cannot understand how to write ur message.How should I write it?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/14196146/7261317 after converting dictionary  ,you can use this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072017/7261317